# Jquery not working in Ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have been trying to make ajax calls with Jquery. When doing so,I miss out the Jquery corners and scroll functionality doesnt work. But the same functionality works fine without Ajax calls. Can anyone provide a solution to this.

My application is in Ruby on Rails and my Ajax call in ROR is as follows.

(link_to_remote "tabname",:url=>{:controller=>'',:action=>''},:update=>'div to be updated')

And when my partial(file) is updated in the div,i am missing my Jquery corners,CSS and motion scroll bar.

I have included my Jquery files in the main page(from where i make an ajax request) and my Jquery corner file is the recent version of Jquery corner plugin. Here is my JQuery corner file 
;

```
(function($) { 

var expr = (function() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    try { div.style.setExpression('width','0+0'); }
    catch(e) { return false; }
    return true;
})();

function sz(el, p) { 
    return parseInt($.css(el,p))||0; 
};
function hex2(s) {
    var s = parseInt(s).toString(16);
    return ( s.length < 2 ) ? '0'+s : s;
};

function gpc(node) {
    for ( ; node && node.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'html'; node = node.parentNode ) {
        var v = $.css(node,'backgroundColor');
        if ( v.indexOf('rgb') >= 0 ) { 
            if ($.browser.safari && v == 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)')
                continue;
            var rgb = v.match(/\d+/g); 
            return '#'+ hex2(rgb[0]) + hex2(rgb[1]) + hex2(rgb[2]);
        }
        if ( v && v != 'transparent' )
            return v;
    }
    return '#ffffff';
};

function getWidth(fx, i, width) {
    switch(fx) {
    case 'round':  return Math.round(width*(1-Math.cos(Math.asin(i/width))));
    case 'cool':   return Math.round(width*(1+Math.cos(Math.asin(i/width))));
    case 'sharp':  return Math.round(width*(1-Math.cos(Math.acos(i/width))));
    case 'bite':   return Math.round(width*(Math.cos(Math.asin((width-i-1)/width))));
    case 'slide':  return Math.round(width*(Math.atan2(i,width/i)));
    case 'jut':    return Math.round(width*(Math.atan2(width,(width-i-1))));
    case 'curl':   return Math.round(width*(Math.atan(i)));
    case 'tear':   return Math.round(width*(Math.cos(i)));
    case 'wicked': return Math.round(width*(Math.tan(i)));
    case 'long':   return Math.round(width*(Math.sqrt(i)));
    case 'sculpt': return Math.round(width*(Math.log((width-i-1),width)));
    case 'dog':    return (i&1) ? (i+1) : width;
    case 'dog2':   return (i&2) ? (i+1) : width;
    case 'dog3':   return (i&3) ? (i+1) : width;
    case 'fray':   return (i%2)*width;
    case 'notch':  return width; 
    case 'bevel':  return i+1;
    }
};

$.fn.corner = function(o) {
    // in 1.3+ we can fix mistakes with the ready state
    if (this.length == 0) {
        if (!$.isReady && this.selector) {
            var s = this.selector, c = this.context;
            $(function() {
                $(s,c).corner(o);
            });
        }
        return this;
    }

    o = (o||"").toLowerCase();
    var keep = /keep/.test(o);                       // keep borders?
    var cc = ((o.match(/cc:(#[0-9a-f]+)/)||[])[1]);  // corner color
    var sc = ((o.match(/sc:(#[0-9a-f]+)/)||[])[1]);  // strip color
    var width = parseInt((o.match(/(\d+)px/)||[])[1]) || 10; // corner width
    var re = /round|bevel|notch|bite|cool|sharp|slide|jut|curl|tear|fray|wicked|sculpt|long|dog3|dog2|dog/;
    var fx = ((o.match(re)||['round'])[0]);
    var edges = { T:0, B:1 };
    var opts = {
        TL:  /top|tl/.test(o),       TR:  /top|tr/.test(o),
        BL:  /bottom|bl/.test(o),    BR:  /bottom|br/.test(o)
    };
    if ( !opts.TL && !opts.TR && !opts.BL && !opts.BR )
        opts = { TL:1, TR:1, BL:1, BR:1 };
    var strip = document.createElement('div');
    strip.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    strip.style.height = '1px';
    strip.style.backgroundColor = sc || 'transparent';
    strip.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    return this.each(function(index){
        var pad = {
            T: parseInt($.css(this,'paddingTop'))||0,     R: parseInt($.css(this,'paddingRight'))||0,
            B: parseInt($.css(this,'paddingBottom'))||0,  L: parseInt($.css(this,'paddingLeft'))||0
        };

        if (typeof this.style.zoom != undefined) this.style.zoom = 1; // force 'hasLayout' in IE
        if (!keep) this.style.border = 'none';
        strip.style.borderColor = cc || gpc(this.parentNode);
        var cssHeight = $.curCSS(this, 'height');

        for (var j in edges) {
            var bot = edges[j];
            // only add stips if needed
            if ((bot && (opts.BL || opts.BR)) || (!bot && (opts.TL || opts.TR))) {
                strip.style.borderStyle = 'none '+(opts[j+'R']?'solid':'none')+' none '+(opts[j+'L']?'solid':'none');
                var d = document.createElement('div');
                $(d).addClass('jquery-corner');
                var ds = d.style;

                bot ? this.appendChild(d) : this.insertBefore(d, this.firstChild);

                if (bot && cssHeight != 'auto') {
                    if ($.css(this,'position') == 'static')
                        this.style.position = 'relative';
                    ds.position = 'absolute';
                    ds.bottom = ds.left = ds.padding = ds.margin = '0';
                    if (expr)
                        ds.setExpression('width', 'this.parentNode.offsetWidth');
                    else
                        ds.width = '100%';
                }
                else if (!bot && $.browser.msie) {
                    if ($.css(this,'position') == 'static')
                        this.style.position = 'relative';
                    ds.position = 'absolute';
                    ds.top = ds.left = ds.right = ds.padding = ds.margin = '0';

                    // fix ie6 problem when blocked element has a border width
                    if (expr) {
                        var bw = sz(this,'borderLeftWidth') + sz(this,'borderRightWidth');
                        ds.setExpression('width', 'this.parentNode.offsetWidth - '+bw+'+ "px"');
                    }
                    else
                        ds.width = '100%';
                }
                else {
                    ds.margin = !bot ? '-'+pad.T+'px -'+pad.R+'px '+(pad.T-width)+'px -'+pad.L+'px' : 
                                        (pad.B-width)+'px -'+pad.R+'px -'+pad.B+'px -'+pad.L+'px';                
                }

                for (var i=0; i < width; i++) {
                    var w = Math.max(0,getWidth(fx,i, width));
                    var e = strip.cloneNode(false);
                    e.style.borderWidth = '0 '+(opts[j+'R']?w:0)+'px 0 '+(opts[j+'L']?w:0)+'px';
                    bot ? d.appendChild(e) : d.insertBefore(e, d.firstChild);
                }
            }
        }
    });
};

jQuery.fn.uncorner = function() { return jQuery('.jquery-corner', this).remove(); };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Provide your code.

Comment: Please be more vague.  Seriously though, it sounds like you're running the calls synchronously instead of asynchronously

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you set the corners and scroll functionality with jQuery (in the document.ready method, most probably) and assuming that your ajax call loads some new html you have to re-execute the code setting the corners.

You can do that in the callback of your ajax method.